# Wordpress search multiple tag combinations

Tags: php, wordpress, search, tags

Im trying to search posts using tag-combinations you can make in my search form. But i cant get the combinations to work.

The (checkbox) options;
Colors: red, blue, black
Shapes: round, square, diamond

I want to display posts that have these tag-combinations:
red AND round
OR
red AND square

I tried this but they doesn't seem to work:
$query = new WP_Query( 'tag=red+round,red+square' );

Wordpress sees this as 'tag=red,round,red,square'.

Anyone with a tip on how i can get this to work or maybe an alternative route?

Comment: What is colors and Shapes? custom taxonomy?

Comment: ok, looks like all these are tags, as per your WP_Query params. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like shorthand version of `WP_Query` will not work in this case, try below parameters for `WP_Query`, detailed information is available here: [WP_Query on WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'red', 'round' ),
            'operator' => 'AND',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'red', 'square' ),
            'operator' => 'AND',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks man, works like a charm. Added new combinations by using $args['tax_query'][] = $tax_array_combination; in a loop.